# Sound sample player in Android

Tags: java, android, compatibility, soundpool

I have a program that plays samples from a drumkit.  It functions perfectly when I try it on one phone but the other phone (while the click is registering and performing the vibration) the sound is not playing.  If the code is correct, why does it not function properly in other devices?!  Here is the code...

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.View;
import com.example.android.searchabledict.R;

public class GameMain extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_main);

    // Initialise SoundPool to play the drum sample sounds
    soundPoolDrums = new SoundPool (8, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    // Create HashMap of sounds
    soundMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
  }

  // Constants and variables for storing sounds for drumkit
  public static final int HIHAT_SOUND_ID=0;
  public static final int RIDE_SOUND_ID=1;
  public static final int CYMBAL_SOUND_ID=2;
  public static final int BASS_SOUND_ID=3;
  public static final int SNARE_SOUND_ID=4;
  public static final int TOMTOMA_SOUND_ID=5;
  public static final int TOMTOMB_SOUND_ID=6;
  public static final int TOMTOMC_SOUND_ID=7;
  private SoundPool soundPoolDrums;
  private Map<Integer, Integer> soundMap;

  /*
   * The next section manages the playback of drum samples
   */

  // High-hat sample player
  public void HatOne (View view) {

      soundMap.put(HIHAT_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumhata, 1)); 
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(HIHAT_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
  }

  // Ride sample player
  public void HatTwo (View view) {

      soundMap.put(RIDE_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumhatc, 1));
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(RIDE_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
      }

  // Crash sample player
  public void Crash (View view) {

      soundMap.put(CYMBAL_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumcrash, 1));   
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(CYMBAL_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
      }

  // Bass sample player
  public void KickDrum (View view) {

      Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
      vib.vibrate(200);

      soundMap.put(BASS_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumkick, 1)); 
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(BASS_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
  }

  // Snare sample player
  public void SnareDrum (View view) {

      Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
      vib.vibrate(150);

      soundMap.put(SNARE_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumsnare, 1)); 
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(SNARE_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
  }

  // High tom sample player
  public void TomOne (View view) {

      Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
      vib.vibrate(120);

      soundMap.put(TOMTOMA_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumtom1, 1)); 
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(TOMTOMA_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
  }

  // Mid tom sample player
  public void TomTwo (View view) {

      Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
      vib.vibrate(120);

      soundMap.put(TOMTOMB_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumtom2, 1)); 
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(TOMTOMB_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
  }

  // Low tom sample player
  public void TomThree (View view) {

      Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
      vib.vibrate(120);

      soundMap.put(TOMTOMC_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumtom3, 1)); 
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(TOMTOMC_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
  }
  // End of sample players section

  // Handlers for Back buttons
  // If tactile back button is pressed then the user is returned to the home screen
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed(){

    soundPoolDrums.release();
    soundPoolDrums = null;

    // play back sound
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soundbackbutton) ;
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    // short vibration
    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vib.vibrate(200);

    Intent s = new Intent (this, Main.class);
    startActivity(s);
  }

  // Handler for back button 
  public void BackButton (View view) {

    soundPoolDrums.release();
    soundPoolDrums = null;  

    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soundbackbutton) ;
    mMediaPlayer.start();

    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vib.vibrate(200);

    Intent s = new Intent (this, Main.class);
    startActivity(s);   
  }

}
```

And the XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fabricblacksmr">

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/BackButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:onClick="BackButton"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonhome"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#00000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/gamemaintext" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="HatOne"
            android:src="@drawable/dhihats" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dride"
            android:onClick="HatTwo"
            android:background="#00000000"/>

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dcrash"
            android:onClick="Crash"
            android:background="#00000000"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="KickDrum"
            android:src="@drawable/dbassdrum"
            android:background="#00000000" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"  
            android:src="@drawable/dsnare"
            android:onClick="SnareDrum"
            android:background="#00000000"/>

    </TableRow>

     <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dtom1"
            android:onClick="TomOne"
            android:background="#00000000"/>

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dtom2"
            android:onClick="TomTwo"
            android:background="#00000000"/>

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dtom3"
            android:onClick="TomThree"
            android:background="#00000000"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/filsdrum"/>

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft ="120dp" 
        android:text="@string/copyright"/>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: What Is the difference between _one phone_ and _other phone_?

Comment: There should be no difference!

Comment: Any ideas on this anyone?  Is my code ok or what is the problem?!

Comment: How are your sounds encoded? mp3? wav? ogg?

Comment: Hi Kris.  They are .wav sounds

Comment: I tried using an mp3 file instead but still no joy